# Compare two different array keys, then do something with the values that dont exist in the 1st array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, wordpress

Arrays seem to be one of those subjects that just doesn't want to click for me.  Seemed easier in SQL... I do hope you can help..

I have two arrays that I wish to compare the keys layouts are completely different, I wish to compare *$first_array->place->name* with *$second_array->post_name* then if a value from the first array doesn't exist in the second then I want to do something about that, probably an Insert statement of sort..

```
  $first_array=simplexml_load_file('xml/file.xml'); // Load an XML file
   echo "<p>Check we are getting a value from the 1st array: ".$first_array->place[0]->name."</p>";
    //echo"<pre>";
    //var_dump($first_array);
    //echo"</pre>";

 $second_array=get_pages(); // Get a list of Posts from WP
   echo "<p>Check we are getting a value from the 2nd array: ".$second_array[0]->post_name."</p>";
    //echo"<pre>";
    //var_dump($second_array);
    //echo"</pre>";
```

**From the First Array..**

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#99 (1) {
  ["place"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#101 (14) {
      ["name"]=>
  string(5) "China"
```

**From the Second Array..**

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#199 (24) {
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(5) "Japan"
```

more

```
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#197 (24) {
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(5) "China"
```

more

```
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#197 (24) {
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(6) "Israel"
```

The difference obviously being Japan, and Israel

### Progress update # 1

I got the the stage where I have two results for the records that DO exist, but I want a distinct list of the records that exist in the XML file, but **DO NOT** exist in the $second_array:

```
<?php 

  $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/regions.xml');
   // echo "<p>".$xml->place[0]->name."</p>";
    echo"<pre>";
    var_dump($xml);
    echo"</pre>";

 $args = array('post_type' => 'page','child_of' => 20,'exclude' => 22);
 $wparray=get_pages($args);
   // echo  "<p>".$wparray[0]->post_name."</p>";
    echo"<pre>";
    var_dump($wparray);
    echo"</pre>";

 foreach($xml as $yregions_places) { 
  for($j=0;$j<count($wparray);$j++) {
   if($yregions_places->name==$wparray[$j]->post_title) { 
    echo "<p style=\"color:green;\">".$yregions_places->name."<p>"; } 
   }
  }

?>
```

Can someone help me get to the next stage? I really am trying!

### Progress update # 2

After Brian's pointer I have managed I think I have both sets of data in an array:

```
 $yregions_xml = (array)simplexml_load_file('xml/regions.xml');
  // echo"<pre>";
  // var_dump($yregions_xml);
  // echo"</pre>";
  $yregions_xml = array_pop($yregions_xml);
   for($j=0;$j<count($yregions_xml);$j++) {
    echo "<p style=\"color:purple;\">".(trim(strtolower($yregions_xml[$j]->name)))."</p>";
   }

 $wpargs = array('post_type' => 'page','child_of' => 20,'exclude' => 22);
 $wparray=get_pages($wpargs);
  // echo"<pre>";
  // var_dump($wparray);
  // echo"</pre>";
  for($j=0;$j<count($wparray);$j++) {
    echo "<p style=\"color:green;\">".(trim(strtolower($wparray[$j]->post_name)))."</p>";
```

So not I have to do some comparison?

### Progress update # 3

```
//store XML data in SimpleXMLObject
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/file.xml'); 
$first_array=array_pop($yregions_xml);

//initiate arrays
$first_array = array();
$second_array = array();

//populate arrays with object data that interests us
foreach($xml->place as $place){
    foreach($place as $name){
    $first_array[] = $name;
    echo "<p style=\"color:green;\">".$name."</p>";
 }
}

$wpargs = array('post_type' => 'page','child_of' => 20,'exclude' => 22);
foreach(get_pages($wpargs) as $page){
    $second_array[] = $page->post_title;
    echo "<p style=\"color:red;\">".$page->post_title."</p>";
}

//perform comparison    
$unique_to_first_array = array_diff($first_array,$second_array);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($unique_to_first_array);
echo "</pre>";

//now do your SQL, etc with this new array
```

### Completed Code

I left all the progress in there, so everyone could see the work in progress, hopefully that will help others more.  I know I have struggled with this.  Thank you @brian_d and @rrapuya for your full and commented answers of assistance.

```
// store XML data in SimpleXMLObject
   $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/file.xml'); 

// initiate arrays
   $first_array = array();
   $second_array = array();

// populate arrays with object data that interests us
   foreach($xml->place as $place){
    foreach($place->name as $name){
     $first_array[] = $name;
     // echo "<p style=\"color:green;\">".$name."</p>";
    }
   }

   $wpargs = array('post_type' => 'page','child_of' => 20,'exclude' => 22);
    foreach(get_pages($wpargs) as $page){
     $second_array[] = $page->post_title;
     // echo "<p style=\"color:red;\">".$page->post_title."</p>";
    }

// perform comparison    
   $unique_to_first_array = array_diff($first_array,$second_array);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($unique_to_first_array);
    echo "</pre>";

//now do your SQL, etc with this new array
```

Comment: you realize that these are objects you are comparing, not arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps. The two key points are populating your arrays from the object data and then using the PHP function [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get values found only in the first array.

```
//store XML data in SimpleXMLObject
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/file.xml'); 

//initiate arrays
$first_array = array();
$second_array = array();

//populate arrays with object data that interests us
foreach($xml->place as $place){
    foreach($place as $name){
        $first_array[] = (string)$name;
    }
}

foreach(get_pages() as $page){
    $second_array[] = $page->post_title;
}

//perform comparision    
$unique_to_first_array = array_diff($first_array, $second_array);

//now do your SQL, etc with this new array
```

Comment: I added the missing semi colon to this line `$second_array[] = $page->post_title;`, I presume that I should be seeing another new array with the differences? The result is `array(0) {
}`, so I am guessing that your supplied code is deliberately incomplete? The phrase of yours I need to be reading into is _populating your arrays from the object data_?

Comment: @Stuart The code is not deliberately incomplete. I have adjusted the first foreach loop which I think should work now. Each name is a SimpleXMLElement object, which is inside of an array of names inside of another SimpleXMLElement object (place). If this still does not work, can you please display some of the actual xml file? Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I getting real used to getting pointers and it looks to simple to accept sometimes.  On your first post the xml loop portion produced one name when echo'ed in the foreach loop.  This revision produces nothing. array(1) {
  ["place"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#101 (14) {
      ["woeid"]=>
      string(8) "28362579"
      ["placeTypeName"]=>
      string(6) "Region"
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "Nordjylland"

Comment: There is definitely something amiss with the first loop.  It is not just checking the 'name' key, so is giving a list of 66 differences in the final array.  I have updated the progress above.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
foreach ($first_array as $arrobj ){

```
for($j=0;$j<count($second_array);$j++){
    if($arrobj->place->name ==$second_array[$j]->post_title){
        //do query here
    }else{
    //do query here

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am not getting any matches, I added comments to try and understand it better, and trimmed and converted to lowercase just in case that was the problem.  If my comments are incorrect I would value a correction.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct approach, it does give me a list of values that match, but does not give me a distinct list of those that do not exist.